# Could not tap ros/fuerte/flann over mxcl/master/flann

Tags: ros, homebrew, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Per the instuction on [installing ROS on OS/X](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#fuerte.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-InstallHomebrew.Install_Homebrew)
I run

```
brew tap ros/fuerte
```

and get this result

```
Cloning into '/usr/local/homebrew/Library/Taps/ros-fuerte'...
remote: Counting objects: 242, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (98/98), done.
remote: Total 242 (delta 141), reused 234 (delta 134)
Receiving objects: 100% (242/242), 47.65 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (141/141), done.
Warning: Could not tap ros/fuerte/flann over mxcl/master/flann
```

I am unsure how to troubleshoot this.  What should I try next?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38756/could-not-tap-ros/fuerte/flann-over-mxcl/master/flann/) by [Nick J Chalko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1591/nick-j-chalko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That should not be a problem, this just means when you do `brew install flann` it will use mxcl/master/flann rather than ros/fuerte/flann.  To install the ros one you would just do `brew install ros/fuerte/flann` instead.

You can continue with out any worries.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0